# AjaxControlToolkit - ReorderList - Doesn't execute the Update Statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ajaxcontroltoolkit

It seems like a lot of people are having trouble with this piece of the control toolkit.  I've looked for a few days on the internet for an answer and haven't been able to find one.  Best solution I've seen so far is "write your own reordering procedure" which I don't want to do.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smgrJobBidding" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPanelReorderList" runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="False" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <ContentTemplate>
<ajaxToolkit:ReorderList ID="rlBiddingJobs" runat="server" AllowReorder="True" 
    DataKeyField="BidID" 
    DataSourceID="sqlDStblJobBids" 
    PostBackOnReorder="True" 
    SortOrderField="Preference" 
    DragHandleAlignment="Left"
    ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
    EnableViewState="False">
    <DragHandleTemplate>
       <div style="float:left;" class="DragHandleClass">
       </div>
    </DragHandleTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteSignup" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
        style="float:right;" Text="Delete" Width="75" Font-Size="Small" Height="20px" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPostingID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostingID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:ReorderList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The SQL datasource object is a little bulky because of the normalized layout of the tables.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDStblJobBids" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobsDB %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.tblJobBids.BidID, dbo.tblJobBids.PostingID, dbo.tblJobBids.EUID, dbo.tblJobBids.Preference, dbo.tblJobPostings.Shift, dbo.tblJobPostings.Needs, 
                  dbo.tblJobPostings.PostedDate, dbo.tblJobPostings.ClosingDate, dbo.tblDepartments.Department, dbo.tblJobs.JobName
FROM dbo.tblJobBids INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblJobPostings ON dbo.tblJobBids.PostingID = dbo.tblJobPostings.PostingID     INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblJobs ON dbo.tblJobPostings.JobID = dbo.tblJobs.JobID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblDepartments ON dbo.tblJobPostings.DepartmentID = dbo.tblDepartments.DeptID
WHERE tblJobPostings.ClosingDate &gt;= (SELECT GETDATE()) AND tblJobPostings.PostingID 
IN (SELECT tblJobBids.PostingID FROM  tblJobBids WHERE tblJobBids.EUID = @EUID)
ORDER BY tblJobBids.Preference Asc;"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tblJobBids WHERE tblJobBids.BidID = @BidID;" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE dbo.tblJobBids SET tblJobs.Preference = @Preference WHERE tblJobs.BidID = @BidID;" >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BidID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="EUID" SessionField="sEUID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Preference" Type="Byte"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BidID" Type="Int32"/>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Select statement is fine, I can drag the items all I want but they "rubber band" back to the position they were in before the drag.  It's like the update statement isn't firing on postback.

I've added some troubleshooting code to count async postbacks inside the update panel and it's definitely posting back.  The data in the database (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express) doesn't appear to be changing.  It could be changing and then changing back... I'm looking at logs to see.

See anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Remove viewstate options from updatepanel, your redorderlist is rebinding on every postback.

Comment: It has EnableViewState="False" ViewStateMode="Disabled", is that not what you mean?  I've actually tried it both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm dumb, I had the data type of the SortOrderField set to "tinyint" in SQL Server 2008.  I changed it from that to just "int" and it's working now.  I created it as "tinyint" initially because preferences are generally only going to be on a scale of something small, like 1-10.  Whatever, it's working now.